# Is this a bug of Scala, when defining a list such as :

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

I want to define a list[Char] in scala, but made a mistake. I missed a single quote character following 'b'. However I got a List[Any] instance. Is it a bug of Scala or normal result?

`scala> val list = List('a',**'b**,'c','d')
list: List[Any] = List(a, 'b, c, d)`

Answer (score 5):

It's not a bug. Single character leading means Symbol in Scala. I just knew that.
I'm sorry. I am just a beginner of Scala.

Answer (score 5):

As woods already answered, the value of `'b'` is a character, while `'b` would be of type `Symbol` (a canonical string that is also a valid Scala identifier).

The `List` type has a very special feature that might be irritating at first: When adding to a list of type `A`, you are not restricted to adding instances of `A`. But if you add something else than an `A` to the list, you get a more general list as result. Example:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}

val list1:List[B] = List(new B(), new B(), new B())
val list2:List[A] = new C() :: list1
```

When you do something like this, Scala finds the more general supertype (in the example above, this is `A`), and returns a list of that type. This is only possible because lists of type `List` are immutable, and when you add an element to the list, you actually create a new list and leave the old list unaltered. And the new list can be of a more general type than the original one.

In your case, you accidentally stumbled over this feature, because the only common supertype for `Char` and `Symbol` is `Any`.